# how i get the mac of ibeacon or BLE

Tags: macos, ibeacon

Recently,I'm doing a IBeacon program.it is like "lightbeacon" in apple store.

the "lightbeacon" only can scan their company's ibeacons.
so my boss made me create a app for my company.

Now,i scan my ibeacon,but i don't get zhe mac address of ibeacon.
The picture is "lightbeacon"，i would like to do like this 。

Now, according to

```html
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central 
       didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral 
       advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData 
       RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI

{

}
```

I know CBPeripheral.identifier can distinguish the ibeacons ,but I need the mac address to make me know the ibeacon. My company's ibeacons are only have  a paper of mac address  .So I need MAC address!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oBSp.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSX/iOS hide BLE MAC addresses and it's not possible to get that information through the API.

You could try to inspect the values for `advertisementData`, it is [a dictionary with keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Advertisement_Data_Retrieval_Keys) that may contain different useful information. That information is usually manufacturer specific, so you need to ask for the structure of the scan response from your iBeacon manufacturer.

Comment: thank you for help me.  but i get the advertisementdata ,but is no BLE MAC address here.i can only  get the major 、 minor and name .

Comment: but i get the advertisementdata ,but is no BLE MAC address here.i can only  get the major 、 minor and name .

Comment: The information is specific to the beacon manufacturer. It is possible that the MAC address could be available on a characteristic so you might need to connect to it. Did you contact the beacon manufacturer for details on scan response? What beacons do you use?

Comment: the beacons are made in china, and the company which made the beacons develop a app.  the name of app is "LightBeacon" ,the app is also  in apple store .In this app ,we can look  the mac address of beacons.

Comment: the beacons are made in china, and the company which made the beacons develop a app.  the name of app is "LightBeacon" ,the app is also  in apple store .In this app ,we can look  the mac address of beacons.

Comment: the beacons are made in china, and the company which made the beacons develop a app.  the name of app is "LightBeacon" ,the app is also  in apple store .In this app ,we can look  the mac address of beacons.

Comment: the beacons are made in china, and the company which made the beacons develop a app.  the name of app is "LightBeacon" ,the app is also  in apple store .In this app ,we can look  the mac address of beacons.

Comment: Could you paste the value of the `advertisementData`? It might help to figure out as I don't have such device at hand.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I have got the MAC address.it is indeed in advertisementData.  it's hiding too deep.  I ask that company's developer,and he talled me.